# react native background geolocation

Tags: react-native, background, geolocation

I have a requirement to save user's geolocation when react-native app is running in background. I know react-native-background-geolocation is available for this but I don't want to use any third party tool for this. Is there a way I can fetch users current location even if the app is running in the background?

Answer (score 2):

With the last [Expo SDK 32](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v32-0-0-is-now-available-6b78f92a6c52) you should be able to to it.

> We’re excited to announce that this release includes initial support for background location, a highly requested feature from many Expo users. You can now define simple JavaScript tasks in your app and register them to receive location updates in the background. Additionally, you can set up geofencing tasks that are triggered when the device enters or leaves specific geographic regions